# Can't load FXML in Clojure using FXMLLoader

Tags: clojure, javafx, fxml

I'm trying to implement the basic JavaFX example shown here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm .  I was able to get the basic stuff working (programmatically creating the gui) and using css, but I'm having trouble with the FXMLLoader.

The java version is this:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
   Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml_example.fxml"));

    stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    stage.show();
}
```

I'm not a Java expert, but I don't think an FXMLLoader object is instantiated ie. there is not a `new FXMLLoader();` statement.  So where is the `load` coming from?

When i try the following clojure code:

```
(ns jfxtwo.core
  (:gen-class
   :extends javafx.application.Application)

  (:import (javafx.application Application)
           (javafx.fxml FXMLLoader)
           (javafx.scene Parent Scene)
           (javafx.stage Stage)))

(defn -main []
  (javafx.application.Application/launch jfxtwo.core (into-array String [])))

(defn -start [this primaryStage]
  (let [loc (clojure.java.io/resource "fxml_example.fxml")
        root (.load FXMLLoader ^java.net.URL loc)
        scene (Scene. root 300 250)]
    (.setScene primaryStage scene)
    (.show primaryStage)))
```

...i get `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method found: load for class java.lang.Class` .

So I put a dot after the FXMLLoader to create an instance: `(FXMLLoader.)` I get this: `ClassCastException java.net.URL cannot be cast to java.io.InputStream`

So this tell me I'm onto something since one of the `load` methods for FXMLLoader supports an InputStream.  I tried forcing the compiler to know the resource is a java.net.URL because that's one of the supported overloads for `FXMLLoader.load`, by placing the call to `(clojure.java.io/resource...)` directly in the call to `(.load...)` but it still doesn't like it (I knew it was a long shot).  I also tried type-hinting, `(.load (FXMLLoader.) ^java.net.URL loc)` and `(.load (FXMLLoader.) #^java.net.URL loc)`, but no dice; it still tries to use the java.io.InputStream version of `load`.

There is also the getClass() call in java which I think is getting the superclass of Application, but I'm not sure what to do with that in clojure-land.

Any ideas on how to load the fxml file?

After that, the java code has `@FXML` annotation for allowing the FXML into private class members.  Is this necessary in clojure (java code breaks when I remove it)?  The @Override annotation doesn't seem to be used in clojure.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the Java syntax, the `load` method being called here appears to be a static method of the `FXMLLoader` class. To call static methods in Clojure, you need to use `(ClassName/methodName args...)` syntax:

```
(FXMLLoader/load ...)
```

(Just checked: `FXMLLoader` has both static and instance `load` methods with multiple signatures. You'll want to call the same method the Java code does; static methods will be called with the `FXMLLoader.load` syntax in Java, instance methods -- `someFXMLLoaderInstance.load`.)

As for the `getClass` method call, it's target is implicitly `this` in Java; in Clojure, you'll have to make the target explicit (`(.getClass this)`).

Comment: Thanks, using static method worked.  However when I tried  `(.getResource (.getClass this) "fxml_example.fxml")` directly instead of `clojure.java.io/resource` it returned nil and the load failed.  That's fine I'll stick with what works.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around my problem by creating the FXMLLoader separately from setting the location.

```
(defn -start [this primaryStage]
  (let [loc (clojure.java.io/resource "fxml_example.fxml")
        fxmlloader (FXMLLoader.)]
    (.setLocation fxmlloader loc) 
    (let [root (.load fxmlloader )
          scene (Scene. root 300 250)]
      (.setScene primaryStage scene)
      (.show primaryStage))))
```